# Can I temporarily set python to default to an earlier version?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I temporarily set python to default to an earlier version?

I have been trying to run a few scripts I [downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/pvdam3/FoEC) written in python 2.7 and my default python version is 3.7.6. I know that I can run one script with 2.7 using: `python2 FoEC.py -i ./testdata/` for instance. However, this script calls other .py scripts also written in 2.7 that I believe are running using 3.7.6 (the keep getting syntax errors which don't appear when run in 2.7). Is there a way to ensure that all scripts are run using python 2.7?

I hope that this makes sense.

Thanks,

Comment: The best way might be to run them in a virtualenv created from your python2 install.  You might need to check the shebang lines in the scripts in case they point directly to `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv with `pyenv` you can set dynamically link the path for `python`. Also I doubt running a script with python2.7 is calling other .py scripts using a different python version. It's probably importing them as packages.

Comment: simple way , rename your python 3 folder to somename then all script will use 2. when you are done rename it back to python 3